# onclick run function react not working reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have the following problem, I have a function but after a few seconds or minutes it runs on its own without clicking.
If someone can help me that I am failing, when I click the function works fine but after a few seconds or minutes it executes itself
Thank you
there I leave the code

```
  import React, { useContext, Fragment, useState,useEffect} from 'react';

import clienteAxios from '../../config/axios';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CRMContext } from '../../context/CRMContext';


const ListadoPedidos =(props) => {
    const [ auth, setAuth ] = useContext(CRMContext);

    const [pedidos, setPedidos] = useState([]);


    const detallePedido = id => {

            props.history.push(`/detalle-pedido/${id}`);

    }

    const eliminarPedido = () => {

    }
    
    useEffect( () => {
        if(auth.token !== '') {
            //query a la API
            const consultarAPI = async () => {
                try {
                    const pedidosConsulta = await clienteAxios.get(`/pedidoscliente/${auth.clienteId}`);

                setPedidos(pedidosConsulta.data);
                } catch (error) {
                    if(error.response.status === 500) {
                        props.history.push('/iniciar-sesion');
                    }
                }
            }
            consultarAPI();
        } else {
            props.history.push('/iniciar-sesion');
        }
        
    }, [] );
return(
        <Fragment>
            <div  class="row justify-content-end">
                    <button type="button" 
                    class="btn btn-dark mr-2"
                    onClick={() => detallePedido(pedido.id)}
                    >
                    Ver detalle</button>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
export default withRouter(ListadoPedidos);
```

Comment: you can post your code to stackblitz and anyone can help you.

Comment: Could you include a longer snippet of your code? Ideally the whole component of possible.

Comment: this is not enough for us to know your problem which start from and can't test to find solutions.

Comment: Everything looks fine... How do you know thar particular function is running? Is it possible that something else is changing the react-router path?

Comment: try passing the event to onClick and set e.preventDefault() at the beginning

Comment: Let me know if that resolves the issue